# Center textview below image view

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I need to center a textview just below an image view.
This is a row screenshot from what I a getting now:

[image]

I need to put the textview with the text "30" below the image view with the thumbs up hand, and centered. The height position is fine as it is now.

Like this:

[image]

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5981b2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/valoracion" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="30"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wanna use margins, which can behave differently on other screens, you could for example use the TextView with an compoundDrawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#5981b2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="30"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/valoracion"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:lines="2"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and add

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

and you are good to go

Comment: Thank you, but using your proposal the textview is put below the image but not centered, it appears now align to the right.

Comment: sorry i did not read ur full question, AndroidGuy is right, u should use android:drawableTop="" or u can put both image and text "30" in linearlayout (vertical) and then center the text :)

Answer (score 1):

Take away

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

The "below" is good. Then use

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView2"
android:layout_marginLeft="xxdp"
```

Set the margin until it appears correct.

Comment: thank you, it works as you propose, but I guess the answer from AndroidGuy was first,is very similar from yours and propose also an improvement to the code. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Remove `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and give `android:layout_marginRight="15dp"` for **textView3** `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:text="30"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: thank you, it works as you propose, but I guess the answer from AndroidGuy was first and it is very similar from yours. Thank you very much for your time and effort.